# Facebook connect and account remove

Tags: facebook, api

I have a website where users can log in with the Facebook oAuth API.

Once the user logs in or registers via Facebook it is stored in my database.

But what I'd like to achieve is, once the user goes to his Facebook application settings page and removes my website app permissions, the used should also be deleted from my database.

Is there any work around to this problem, if this is not possible via the Facebook oAuth API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Deauthorise Callback URL` by Navigating to `Settings > Advanced section` of your application. Whenever a User Deauthorises your Facebook app, Facebook performs a HTTP POST of [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) to your URL. You may use the field `user_id` to determine which User has deauthorised your app.

Comment: Clever, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would do the following:

1. Add a date to his last log in to your site.
2. Have cron job check for old, unused accounts.
3. Send an email to the user's email address (or Facebook message mail) telling him his account is due to expire soon.
4. Delete account from database.

Comment: this is a really clever solution!